# Angular Try Catch error handling for 404 not found

Tags: typescript, angular9, angular14

I am getting data from a JSON file using an HTTP client. After using subscribe I am reading the JSON data. Here I want to check if the path is wrong to wish to send a 404 not found error message.

```
getMapConfig(): Observable<MapReportConfigModel> {
    let mapConfigData = `assets/mapReportConfig1.json`;
    return this.httpClient.get<MapReportConfigModel>(mapConfigData);
}
```

### Load map method

```
loadMap(): void {
    try {
      this.mapReportConfigModel
        .getMapConfig()
        .subscribe((configData) => {
          this.configData = configData;

          // Initialize map
          mapboxgl!.accessToken = this.configData.accessToken;
          this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: this.configData.container,
            center: [this.configData.centerLat, this.configData.centerLng],
          });
         
// check API key is wrong.
          this.map.on("error", (response) => {
            this.showError(
              "500",
              "mapReport.err_no_map_reports",
              "mapReport.err_generating_map_report_message"
            ).subscribe(() => {
              this.router.navigateByUrl("/dashboard");
              return;
            });
          });
        })
        .add(() => {
          // Hide spinner
          this.loadingService.hide(processId);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Here I want to show if that error is 404. then want to show check it in catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RxJS Observable `error`. You are currenly only using `next`

```
this.mapReportConfigModel.getMapConfig()
    .subscribe({
      next: (data)=>console.log('data',data),
      error: (err)=>console.log('error',err),
      complete:()=>console.log('complete')
    });
```

Also this is the same thing, which is closer to what you have:

```
 .subscribe(
      (result) => {
        // Handle result
        console.log(result)
      },
      (error) => {
        this.errors = error;
      },
      () => {
        // 'onCompleted' callback.
        // No errors, route to new page here
      }
    );
```

https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable

Comment: you should not wrap the subscribe in a try / catch